# How to compare to arrays and count the elements that don't match - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to compare two arrays. Each one has three letters, if the letters are different it returns a number that is equal to the letters that didn't match for example:

```
arr1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
arr2 = ["A", "D", "E"]
```

I need a method that returns 2. Because there are two elements that don't match.

Comment: Why don't you just do `(arr1 - arr2).length`?

Comment: It gives me this error `undefined method `-' for "A":String`

Comment: It works fine [here](https://repl.it/FILI).

Comment: @Eli, such reasoning is often messed up by the presence of duplicate values. Suppose `arr1 = [1,1]; arr2 = [1,2]`. Then `(arr1-arr2).size #=> 0`, but the answer is `1`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, maybe it should be `[(arr1 - arr2).size, (arr2 - arr1).size].max`?

Comment: Are the arrays always sorted? Do you need to count if the positions are different?

Comment: You need to clarify "if the letters are different". I think what you mean is that you want to count the number of indices `i` for which `arr1[i] != arr2[i]`. Programming requires precision, with words as well as code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-count).

```
arr1.zip(arr2).count { |a1,a2| a1!=a2 }
  #=> 2
```

Note

```
arr1.zip(arr2) 
  #=> [["A", "A"], ["B", "D"], ["C", "E"]]
```

Equivalently, use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

```
[arr1, arr2].transpose.count { |a1,a2| a1!=a2 }
  #=> 2
```

Comment: Your answer, like always, is both very ruby like and accurate.

Comment: Also: `arr1.zip(arr2).map(&:uniq).map(&:length).count(1)` to boil it down more incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your arrays are the same length and don't have duplicates, this is going to be faster:

```
arr1.length - (arr1 & arr2).length
# => 2
```

Comment: I would expect the result would be 2 if `arr1 = [1,2]` and `arr2 = [2,1]`, but you obtain zero. Perhaps we interpreted the question differently.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, it's hard to say given the phrasing. What is meant by a “match”? Is position important or not?